# posting two variables through jquery and ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble getting two variables to post using ajax and jquery upon pressing a button on a confirm window. I can get either variable to display individually, but when I try to post two at the same time it won't work.

EDIT - Problem solved. Didn't include a file I needed. My fault!

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteSomething(\'' . $replyID .'\', \'' .$tableName. '\',\'' .$replyBy. '\')" />';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function deleteSomething(replyID, tableName, replyBy)
{
if (!confirm("Are you sure?"))
    return false;
$.post('pageprocessing.php',"replyID=" + replyID + "&tableName=" + tableName + "&replyBy=" + replyBy, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
}
```

Here's my script on pageprocessing.php. All three of the values that I post echo properly, I just can't figure out why they aren't being deleted.

```
if(isset($_POST['replyID']) && isset($_POST['tableName']) && isset($_POST['replyBy'])){

    if($_POST['tableName'] == "replies" && $_POST['replyBy'] == $userid){
        echo $replyID = $_POST['replyID']; //echoing variables to make sure the page gets this far
        echo $replyBy = $_POST['replyBy'];
        echo $tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
        mysql_query("delete from replies where repliesID = $replyID "); //I can type this query into terminal and it deletes. Why won't it delete from here?
    }
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ look the examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post's variables should all be concatenated.

```
$.post('pageprocessing.php',"replyID=" + replyID + "&tableName=" + tableName, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

You could alternatively use objects

```
$.post('pageprocessing.php',{
    replyID     : replyID, 
    tableName   : tableName
}, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly. I'll accept your answer as soon as the 9 min limit allows me!

Comment: As long as your php script is the one executing the delete query, then there should be no problem. Update your code with the delete code happening on the server, and I'll ensure nothing seems off :)

Answer (score 0):

No eqaul sign needed ! Use it like this

```
$.post('pageprocessing.php',{ replyID : replyID, tableName :  tableName}, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

Comment: It wasn't me. However, I still tried to do what you suggested and it didn't work.